# No Idea What To Do

Tags: hard-drive

I purchased an HP tower brand new back in 2008. Its processor is a 'Core 2 Duo', with a 500 gig hard drive and Windows 7 Professional. Due to the outdated processor and increasingly more complicated software packages, the machine struggled to perform effectively. I acquired a used HP tower on Ebay for a good price. The machine is an updated version of my old one, only equipped with an Intel i5 processor and a 250 gig hard drive. The new machine has no software installed except for Windows 7 Professional.

Because the HP towers are so similar, (except for the motherboards and processors) I thought it would be easy to just exchange hard drives and call-it-a-day. However, the newly acquired machine would not boot-up with my old hard drive. I reinstalled the 250 gig hard drive as the primary and installed my old 500 gig hard drive as the secondary. It was recognized as the 'D' drive, but will not open any of the files.

I wish to migrate the files from my old 500 gig hard drive to the 250 gig, or have the machine boot-up with the 'D' drive as the primary so that all of the software installed on it executes as it did formerly. The old 500 gig hard drive is loaded with software, with some programs that cannot be replaced.

Can you please offer a substantive solution(s)?

Comment: The easiest way is to boot in the old tower, copy the personal files to an external device. Then install the old drive in the new tower, format it and use it as a data partition. You may then copy the old files over. Access with a different user may not be easy due to encryption and/or other settings.

Answer (score 3):

You have a totally different motherboard in the new system that requires different drivers for just about every single component.
And most of those drivers are not available in Windows 7 out of the box, so your old systems boot-process doesn't know how to find it's own harddrive, let alone the rest of the hardware.

A fresh install is usually the best way to go. But if you REALLY want to attempt this there is method that might just work. This is not for the faint of heart. From your question I figure you're not really that computer-savvy so doing a complicated Windows installation might not be for you..

- First put the disk back in the old system, and make a full system-backup. This method may destroy your Windows installation during the attempt, so make sure you can restore to the initial state first, just in case that is needed.
- Go the the HP website and find the driver downloads for the new system (Please note: If this is a Z-series workstation you may need to go the HP Enterprise site (www.hpe.com) in stead of the normal HP site.)
- At a minimum you need the "storage" drivers. You probably want the network card drivers as well, because those are probably the first you need after the upgrade install in order to connect the computer to the internet so you can download all the other drivers you need.
- Use WinRAR or 7-zip or WinZip to open the Storage-drivers file (Yes.. It is probably a EXE file, but it should still be possible to open it as if it is a zip or rar file.) Extract all the content and put this on a FAT32 formatted USB stick.
- Get yourself a recent Windows 7 installation medium and put this on another USB stick. (I recommend you use the Microsoft "Media Creation Tool" to download the image and put it on a USB stick.)
- On the new system go into the Bios setup. Make sure the USB is configured as a bootable device and make sure the BIOS is configured to run in UEFI mode with CSM support enabled (if that option is available). Sometimes CSM mode is called "Legacy Mode" In that case enable that.
- Put your harddisk in the new system. (You did make a backup, didn't you ?)
- First try to boot straight from the harddisk. If you are really lucky this might just work (which means the Bios configuration was all that was needed.) In that case you just need to download and install all drivers.
- If it didn't boot up insert the Windows 7 installation USB stick and boot from that instead.
- Continue with the Win7 install to the point where you can select the harddisk to which to install. Most likely Windows 7 doesn't see the harddisk but you are offered the option of loading extra drivers. Now you need the 2nd USB with the extracted storage drivers. Try every driver on there until the Windows 7 setup can see the harddisk.
- Now continue with a "Upgrade" installation over the existing old Windows 7 installation.
  This should work and after this is finished you should be able to boot in your original Windows 7 install. You will still need to do a lot of driver upgrades using the normal driver upgrade instructions from HP. Don't forget to also update the storage drivers. The driver-loading during the Win7 setup didn't install the full driver to the fresh Windows 7, so you do need to repeat that.

If something goes wrong you can still revert to your backup (you did make one I hope...)
After this trick you may need to re-activate your Windows 7 installation.

**Please note:** 
Windows 7 will go end-of-life in January 2020. You may want to upgrade to Windows 10 before that.
The free Windows 7 to Windows 10 upgrade still works. (Use that same Media Creation Tool to generate a Windows 10 USB stick. Don't boot form the stick, but just start the Windows 10 setup on the USB stick from within the Windows 7 install and it will do the upgrade.)
If you do the Windows 10 upgrade on the old system it should be MUCH easier to move the disk to the new system as Windows 10 will support the newer hardware out-of-the-box.
You still need to check the Bios setting for CSM/Legacy mode though, Your original Windows 7 installation was Legacy/CSM only and Windows 10 will inherit that.